# Yosemite file permissions/ownership issue

Tags: macos, permission

I'm no stranger to OSX and a while back I upgraded to Yosemite at rollout.

I'm a web developer an I'm encountering a strange behaviour with file permissions ever since upgrading. For example, I'm using the command line to pull in files through Git or Composer. Previously, when I did this, I was automatically the owner of these new folders and files and had read/write access.

However, when I perform the same operations, I'm no longer the owner and have to go about `chown` and `chmod`ing various folders in order to get going.

I haven't heard of anyone else experiencing this. Any ideas?

Chris

Comment: Out of interest, who owns the the files when you pull, what permissions are they and what do you expect them to be?

Comment: I'm not sure who owns the files. They are publicly available in repositories hosted on Github etc.

Comment: sorry, I meant when you pull and the file isn't owned by you, who *is* it owned by? When you pull a new file what is the output of `ls -l <file>`? And what do you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution which was much more localised.

I needed to `chown -R` my composer directory. For some reason, I wasn't the owner. After running this command, the issue was resolved.